# Slide Distance Rather than Factor

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to move an edge along another edge by exactly 7.81m. *edit: How do I do this?* I tried using the slide tool using `Shift`+`V`, `G` `G`. However, the only distance setting is a factor.

If I could type in 7.81m there, that'd be perfect.

There are a ton of settings in the move dialog box, but I can't figure them out.

Any advice would be great. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hi :). You cannot slide vertices/edges using metric units. They only work with the *Move Tool*. But there are workarounds.

Comment: I figured there would be at least one workaround. Can you suggest one? Thanks!

Comment: I edited by question to explicitly ask a question if that helps.

Comment: Hi Becca :) One of the workarounds is using a *custom orientation*. I'll add an answer when i get to it later today.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *Move Tool* if you need absolute values.

To align the *Move tool* to your edge orientation, switch transform orientation to *Normal*.

[image]

---

Or you can create a custom orientation.

1. Select two vertices along perpendicular edge.
2. Click the little <kbd>+</kbd> to create a custom Orientation
3. Use the move tool.

[image]

Comment: Hi hi. I'm sure this is correct, but I haven't had a chance to try it out yet and may not for a little bit. As soon as I've verified it works, I'll accept your answer :)